# Boolean Array change in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, boolean, iteration

I am stuck on this code problem - I need to iterate through an array of booleans 100 times. Instructions:

Cats in hats

You have 100 cats.  Your rules are simple: whenever you visit a cat, you toggle it's hat status (if it already has a hat, you remove it.. if it does not have a hat, you put one on). All of the cats start hat-less. You cycle through 100 rounds of visiting cats. In the 1st round, you visit every cat. In the second round, you visit every other cat. In the nth round, you visit every nth cat.. until the 100th round, in which you only visit the 100th cat.  At the end of 100 rounds, which cats have hats?

New to Ruby from JS and stuck on how to implement this. I think my logic is right, I just can't get it to change the value of the booleans in the array.

Any advice much appreciated!

Thanks

```
def cats_in_hats

 cats = []

 i = 0
 while i< 100
 cats << false 
 i = i + 1 
 end 

 puts cats 


 round = 1;

 while round < 10

  # 
  cats = cats.each_with_index do |cat, idx|
    if idx % round == 0
      puts "toggle index #{idx} divisible by round #{round}"
      cat = !cat
      puts cat 
    end
  end

  round = round + 1 

 end 

puts cats 

end

puts "------Cats in Hats------"
puts cats_in_hats == [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to ruby. Someone nicely provided an explanation of what the issues were with your code. I thought I would give you a quick run down on the power of objects in ruby instead.

Let's start with `Cat`. What can it do? Well:

- It can have a hat
- It starts out without a hat
- It can put on and take off the hat

Okay so lets make an `Object` for that:

```
class Cat
  def initialize
    @hat = false # start out without a hat
  end
  def toggle_hat
    !@hat   # in case you just want to tip your hat in salutation to JörgWMittag
  end
  def toggle_hat!
    @hat = toggle_hat # @hat equals not(@hat) e.g. @hat = not(true) to take off the hat
  end
  def has_hat?
    @hat # does it have a hat true or false
  end
end
```

Perfect there is a `Cat`. Now let's look at the problem.

We need to loop through 100 `cats`. Okay

```
cats = Array.new(100) { Cat.new }
```

Now we have 100 cats. Let's start looping

```
#loop from 1 up to 100 providing the loop number (n)
1.upto(100).each do |n| 
  # for each n we skip over the preceding n and step by n
  (n..100).step(n) do |idx| 
    # pick the appropriate cat (ruby indexes start at 0) 
    # toggle his hat
    cats[idx - 1].toggle_hat!
  end
end
```

Great all our `Cat`s have been looped through and toggled now lets count the ones with hats on

```
# will count each cat where has_hat? is true
cats.count {|cat| cat.has_hat? }
#=> 10
```

This would generally be expressed more idiomatically as `cats.count(&:has_hat?)`. This uses ruby's `Symbol#to_proc` sugar and means call the method `has_hat?` on each element yielded to the block as shown more explicitly above.

We can also collect them

```
cats.map.with_index {|cat,idx| idx + 1 if cat.has_hat? }.compact
#=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Tada `Object`s are amazing and make for fantastically readable simplistic code. [Full Example](https://repl.it/LXK4/2)

Comment: Don't forget `cats.count(&:has_hat?)` as a short-hand for same.

Comment: @tadman I would have but *"New to Ruby from JS"* caused me to use a more explicit block syntax

Comment: Not as a first step, you've got the right idea unpacking it slowly, but as an example of how Ruby can really minify solutions without over-complicating things. `cats.count(function(cat) { return cat.has_hat() })` is now `cats.count(cat => cat.has_hat())` in ES6, so there's a lot of similarity these days.

Comment: @tadman added for edification. Although I find that the real complication for people is the preceding `&:` notation

Comment: An even better explanation, nice!

Comment: Note: your method names violate standard Ruby style. Bangs are only used for the more surprising version of a pair of methods. In your case, there is only one method, so it shouldn't have a bang.

Comment: @JörgWMittag very astute of you it was borrowed, more or less, from the way `rails` uses `#toggle!(attribute)` but I have updated the code to more accurately reflect a stateful mutation (still not perfect but it gets the point across)

Comment: Yeah, Rails' coding conventions differ from Ruby's. (I remember that for a long time, they advocated `for` / `in` oder `#each`, for example, whereas Ruby is the other way around.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would be perfectly fine to only have a bang method that modifies the object, when a non-bang method makes no sense. But having both works too.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Of course, there is nothing *wrong* with that, it just doesn't conform to the Coding Style used by the core library, standard libraries and the majority of the Ruby community. (DSLs or the Rails community are a different matter, though.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag What's bigger, the Rails community or rubyists _not_ in the Rails Community? ;)

Comment: @MarkThomas To paraphrase **John Lennon** and *Jeremy Hillary Boob, PhD*: **You [write ruby]?** *Old [ruby], middle, a dialect, pure.* **Well, do you [write ruby]?** *You know, I'm not sure!* - Yellow Submarine (1968)

Answer (score 1):

```
cats = cats.each_with_index do |cat, idx|
  # ...
  cat = !cat
end
```

This is the problem. All objects in Ruby are represented in memory by pointers, and these pointers are copied around to pass objects to methods/blocks/etc. So when you do `each_with_index`, Ruby copies the pointer of each element into your block-local variable `cat` one at a time.

Now when you say `cat = !cat`, this is what Ruby does

1. Find the `!` method for the object pointed to by `cat` and call it. This returns a pointer to the object `true` or the object `false`
2. Overwrite the block-local variable `cat` with that new pointer

At no point does that new pointer end up in your `cats` array!

I can think of two main solutions to this problem:

1. Instead of storing Boolean objects (which are immutable), store mutable objects in `cats`. Then you can call a method on each `cat` that tells it to mutate its state (this is what @engineersmnky's code does)
2. Instead of using your block-local variable `cat`, tell Ruby to copy the new pointer directly into the array: `cats[idx] = !cat`

Answer (score 0):

```
def cats_in_hats
  cats = []

  i = 0
  while i < 100
    cats << false 
    i = i + 1 
  end 

  p cats 

  round = 1;

  while round < 100

  cats = cats.collect!.with_index do |cat, idx|
    idx % round == 0 ? !cat : cat
  end

  round = round + 1 

  end 

  p cats 

end

puts "------Cats in Hats------"
puts cats_in_hats
```

The problem with your initial code is that you were never "doing" anything in your `each_with_index` block.  when you used `cat = !cat` you were only changing that item within the scope of the loop and never creating a new array.  Using `.collect!.with_index`[map/collect!.with_index(to get the index)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) you can perform an operation on each item in an array and return a new array with every iteration.  This is similar to how JavaScript's `map` function works.  Let me know if you need further explanation.